# Count of memcached keys prematurely expired?

Tags: memcached

Is there a way to easily the exact statistic of the count of keys that memcached is expiring before their assigned expiry time due to memory pressure?

I am aware that memcached provides dozens of stats ([Memcache stats understanding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15110999/memcache-stats-understanding)), but its not clear to me if any of those stats communicate the answer to this question in particular.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Memcache stats understanding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15110999/memcache-stats-understanding)

Comment: It's not clear to me from the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15110999/memcache-stats-understanding that any of those stats answer this question. Moreover, there is tons of extraneous information in that answer; I would like to know the precise (field|stat|key name|whatever) that communicates the count of keys prematurely expired.

Comment: 'evictions': Number of objects removed from the cache to free up memory for new items because Memcached reached it's maximum memory setting (limit_maxbytes).

Comment: Thanks! That may be it - what happens to objects that are already expired? Are they counted in the evictions too? Or does evictions only count objects with TTLs > 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memcached has a large number of stats that can be easily fetched with the `STATS` command, and you can also ask for `STATS items`, `STATS settings`, `STATS sizes`, and `STATS slabs` - among several others as well.

For the main `STATS` command, on item returned is '**evictions**' - Number of objects removed from the cache to free up memory for new items because Memcached reached it's maximum memory setting.

If an item has expired (ie TTL has run out - by number of seconds or timestamp), but is still in memory, it will return the cache-miss.